# openldap memberOf not showing user in group

Tags: cache, openldap

When I do an ldapsearch for a newly created user and ask for its goup membership  the query does not return the expected answer even though this user exists in a group.

For example :

```
# ldapsearch -x  -D "cn=Admin,dc=xxx,dc=yyy" -w'XXXXXX'   -b 'uid=cberch,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc='yyy' memberOf
```

I get:

```
# cberch, people, xxx.yyy
dn: uid=cberch,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=yyy
```

And that's it, then I try:

```
# ldapsearch -x  -D "cn=Admin,dc=xxx,dc=yyy" -w'XXXXXXX'-b 'cn=members_staff,ou=group,dc=xxx,dc=yyy'  |grep cberch
```

I can find my user:

```
member: uid=cberchiche,ou=people,dc=xxx,dc=yyy
```

I noticed that hours later the "memberOf" query returns the user and its group.

Is there some caching mechanism in openldap ? Is it possible to force the reload manually ?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Vince

Comment: How is your memberof overlay configured?

Comment: Hi !#  slapcat -n 0 | grep olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {0}memberof.la
olcModuleLoad: {0}refint.la
olcModuleLoad: {0}ppolicy.la

Comment: Better to edit information into your question than to have it be a comment. Also, this only seems to show that you've loaded the module, not that you've configured it.